# SQL select from another table values comma separated where ids are contained in a string

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table:

```
ID | Type | Name
______________________
1  | 3   | Electronic
2  | 4   | Mechanical
3  | 6   | Other
```

and another table

```
ID | Name | Type
_____________________
1  | x5f2 | 34
2  | x5f3 | 46
```

What I want to do is select an entry in the second table and have it like this:

```
ID | Name | TypeNames
__________________________________
1  | x5f2 | Electronic, Mechanical
2  | x5f3 | Mechanical, Other
```

I tried using the SQL FIND_IN_SET function but I can't get the Type field from the first table separated by commas and have all of them on the same line.

Comment: You're heading down a very dark road. Turn around where possible.

Comment: Trust me, I would :(

Comment: You don't even have a separator in the type field?

Comment: Nope, and I'm afraid I can't change that..

Comment: Good - so you only ever and will only ever have single digit types?

Comment: It's time to fire the one who designed the tables relation and hire someone qualified. Think about [DB normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

Comment: Yes, only single digits

Comment: I see it like this: Relational databases aren't some kind of panacea. They're very useful for solving a set of problems, but they have rules. If you're not going to bother with the rules, don't bother with the relational database.

Comment: Good luck when you'll have more than 12 types. How would you differenciate `12` from being the 12th type with the types `1` and `2` ?

Comment: @cid op has already stated type will only ever be single digit.

Comment: @P.Salmon that's for today. Let's hope users won't have the great idea to feed the DB with more types in the future. But at least, we can always trust user inputs

Comment: @cid - no chance, that's what validation,change control and data cleansing are for..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT table2.ID, 
       table2.Name,
       GROUP_CONCAT(table1.Name) TypeNames
FROM table1 
JOIN table2 ON LOCATE(table1.Type, table2.Type)
GROUP BY table2.ID, 
         table2.Name;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6ba243d7fe56933d3ce0a74772608415)

Comment: I get a very very long string in TypeNames with the first Type repeating itself a lot

Comment: ah it works, i had some code there before. thank you!

Comment: @VlasiuRobert If you do not like LOCATE you may join by `INSTR(table2.Type, table1.Type)`.